# Encryption & Decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, sha1

I want to have a Encryption using SHA1. My Code is

```
public static string EncryptPassword(string password)
{
    try
    {
        SHA1 sha1 = new SHA1Managed();
        var bytehash = sha1.ComputeHash(new MemoryStream(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(password)));
        var stringhash = new ASCIIEncoding().GetChars(bytehash).ToString();

        return stringhash;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Some Exception....
    }

    return null;
}
```

It's not working. It only return System.Char[]. What am I doing wrong in this

Comment: You need to express your hash as a hex string, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: The normal way of converting a byte array of non-character data to a string is to express it as a hex string. Treating bytes as ascii is inherently lossy and the wrong way to solve this problem.

Comment: @spender: Please post your comment as an answer since the accepted answer is incorrect.

Comment: @GregS No. The question is incorrect. Until OP accepts this to be the case, I am leaving notes as comments. I would prefer to close as a dupe rather than repeating the same info of the linked answers, but that also doesn't seem quite appropriate yet.

Comment: Com'on guys!!!!! I asked a specific question and got a specific answer. How the question is dulplicate????

Comment: @Jain : the reason that this question is problematic is that you are attempting to do something that is fundamentally broken by design. As I've stated before, the correct way to turn a byte array into a string is either as a hex string (or even a base64 encoded string). Your method here will create garbage. If that's truly what you want, then fine, but it's not very likely, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's what `ToString()` returns from an array of chars...

try

```
new string(new ASCIIEncoding().GetChars(bytehash));
```

and choose Maurice's answer, which is smarter ;)

Comment: ...but a binary hash isn't ascii... what's this meant to do? make a garbage string?

Comment: @jain ascii encoding is values from 0 to 127, but the hash is bytes with value from 0 to 255. The idea of directly converting a hash to ascii is broken by design and you will lose information by doing this.

Comment: @spender: Currently I used to do Encryption using MachineKey Class. Would like to ask: Which Encryption Method is really good in terms of performance and security?

Answer (score 3):

Use `GetString` instead of `GetChars`

```
var stringhash = new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(bytehash);
```

However Spender wrote you a comment on your question with a link to another question that will help you resolve your actual problem. (@Spender thanks for this).

Comment: Same issue. The hash will contain values that aren't ascii. What's this actually going to do?

Comment: @spender I agree it is a bit useless; however this answer does what he wants; converting the bytes to an useless string.